# Computing subresultants

Tags: polynomials

Let $f=f(x), g=g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$
Write $f=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ and $g=(x-b_1)\cdots(x-b_m)$,
where $n,m$ are natural numbers (distinct or not).
Let $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$.

> How do we compute the `subresultants` of $f-\lambda$ and $g-\mu$?

I really apologize if my question is trivial; truly, I have just downloaded WolframMathematica 11.3 for a 15-day free trial.

BTW, I have tried WolframAlpha, but it only works if we take small $m$'s and $n$'s (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056189/computing-subresultants-in-wolframalpha) question).

> What if we further assume that $a_1=b_1$? (the other roots may be distinct); can `subresultants` be computed in a simpler way?

Obviously, we can just replace $b_1$ by $a_1$ in the expressions of `subresultants` (after having computed them) and obtain a slightly nicer expressions. What I mean is that Mathematica will compute `subresultants` knowing that $a_1=b_1$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this suffice?  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subresultant.html

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thank you (I have seen that page). Unfortunately, it did not help me when $\deg(f)=\deg(g) \geq 3$. The problem is that I am interested in the subresultants of $f-\lambda$ and $g-\mu$, which are more complicated than those of $f$ and $g$. ($\lambda$ and $\mu$ appear in $s_1$..).

Comment: Oh, perhaps you meant that I should download that page to Wolfram Notebook and see the code lines with FullSimplify etc. Unfortunately, I still have not succeeded to compute the subresultants..How do I get the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[a[i_]] := Subscript[a, i];
Format[b[i_]] := Subscript[b, i];

m = 3; n = 3;

f[x_] = Times @@ (x - Array[a, m]);

g[x_] = Times @@ (x - Array[b, n]);

sub = Subresultants[f[x] - λ, g[x] - μ, x] // FullSimplify;
```

The use of [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) makes this calculation quite slow.

The problem is that the complexity of the longer expressions grows rapidly with increasing values of `m` and `n`.

```
LeafCount /@ sub

(* {1205, 563, 19, 1} *)

List /@ sub // Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For the special case when `b[1] == a[1]`

```
g[x_] = Times @@ (x - Array[b, n]) /. b[1] -> a[1];

sub = Subresultants[f[x] - λ, g[x] - μ, x] // FullSimplify;

LeafCount /@ sub

(* {320, 60, 13, 1} *)

List /@ sub // Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! This is very helpful. So $s_2=a_1+a_2+a_3-b_1-b_2-b_3$. Actually, I am only interested in $s_1$, which is quite complicated.. Is there a way to compute only $s_1$, or perhaps there is (almost) no difference between computing all the $s_i$'s and just $s_1$? (It seems that $s_0$ is the most complicated to compute, then $s_1$ etc.).

Comment: It would likely be useful to calculate only `s1` if you need larger values of `m` and `n`; however, you would need to code that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. ok.

Comment: Please, if we further assume that $a_1=b_1$ (the other roots may be distinct), can  $s_1$ be computed in a simpler way? Obviously we can just replace $b_1$ by $a_1$ in the above expression of $s_1$ and obtain a slightly nicer expression, but I mean that Mathematica will compute $s_1$ knowing that $a_1=b_1$.